# How to make percentage distribution with least rounding error

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, percentage

I am dealing with a problem when I have to assign a specific portfolio budget to buy stocks. The stock price and percentage of budget allotted to each stock is known and lets assume that the budget is $100,000. Given below is a generic percentage calculation that I am currently using:

```js
data = [
  {stock: 'INFY', price: 1122.9, percent: 0.304},
  {stock: 'SUNPHARMA', price: 890.95, percent: 0.177},
  {stock: 'TCS', price: 2597.7, percent: 0.123},
  {stock: 'HCLTECH', price: 856, percent: 0.117},
  {stock: 'LUPIN', price: 2019, percent: 0.112},
  {stock: 'DIVISLAB', price: 1097, percent: 0.085}, 
  {stock: 'CADILAHC', price: 409.4, percent: 0.082}   
];
  
var budget = 100000;
var actual = 0;

for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ in data ) {
  shares = Math.floor((budget * data[i].percent) / data[i].price);
  document.write( data[i].stock + ': ' );
  document.write( shares );
  document.write( '<br />' );
  spent = shares * data[i].price;
  actual += spent;  
}

document.write( '<hr />' );

document.write( 'Budget: ' + budget );
document.write( '<br />' );
document.write( 'Actual spent: ' + actual );
```

What should be the approach / algorithm / code to find the optimal way to use the budget such that:

- Difference between budget and actual spent is least
- Actual spent should not exceed budget

To meet the above two conditions it is ok to deviate from the percentage of budget allotted to each stock but the deviation should be least possible

Comment: What is `i++ in data` supposed to do?

Comment: @Jonathan the for loop is just for the display. Check 'Run Code Snippet' to see what I mean.

Comment: I know what it does, but what is it *supposed* to do[?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)[!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: The loop ideally should do such a percentage spread of shares such that the difference between budget and actual spent is least and actual spent does not exceed the budget. While doing this it should be ok to deviate from the percentage of budget allotted to each stock but the deviation should be least possible.

Answer (score 1):

Add one more important variable `minPrice` .

Once initial allotment is done based on the percentages you can create an additional `while` loop that keeps adding shares while the remainder is greater than or equal to the minimum price.

```
var budget = 100000;
var actual = 0;
var minPrice = Infinity;

for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ in data ) {
  data[i].shares = Math.floor((budget * data[i].percent) / data[i].price);    
  actual +=  data[i].shares * data[i].price;
  minPrice  = data[i].price < minPrice ? data[i].price : minPrice;    
}


var remain = budget - actual;
// attempts to add 1 share each iteration until not enough left to buy any shares
while( remain >= minPrice){
    for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].price <= minPrice){
            data[i].shares +=1;
            remain -= data[i].price;
            actual += data[i].price
        }
    }    
}
```

Since initial data is sorted by highest portfolio percentage, higher priority would automatically get more shares first if their price is less than remainder of budget

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this. But this only adds up shares in the last stock- http://jsfiddle.net/a3ez585x/. But this surely gives me the right direction.